# R: date format issue (from character to unknown format)

Tags: r, date, format

I have a .csv file with several dates presented like this: "26-11-21". These dates are in character format and when I try to convert them to date format using the following code, they are converted to Unknown format and appear as "2021-11-26":

```
file$Date1 <- as.Date(as.character(file$Date1),format="%d-%m-%y")
```

I have also tried the two following codes but it does not work either:

```
file$Date1 <- as.Date(paste0(as.character(file$Date1)), format = "%d-%m-%y")

file$Date1 <- format(as.Date(file$Date1, "%d-%m-%y"), "%d-%m-%y")
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "Unknown format"? `as.Date("26-11-21", format="%d-%m-%y")` works as expected.

Comment: The problem is that it does not work as expected and instead of returning a date format, R returns an "Unknown format" and it now appears as "2021-11-26".

Comment: How do you know that 'R returns an "Unknown format"'? What does that mean? `"2021-11-26"` (Y-m-d) is how R prints the date if it has been parsed correctly.

Comment: Are you confused about printing of vectors of class `Date`?

Comment: Oh all right, thank you. When looking at the table and running the mouse over the header, R indicates the format as "Unkown", but using "str(file)" it indicates the format as "Date", so I suppose everything is ok then?

Comment: Is your question actually about RStudio's data viewer?

Comment: Yes indeed, I am using RStudio's data viewer.

Comment: OK. I'd say everything is fine then and you have run into a limitation of the data viewer. I wouldn't worry about this.